# How to do aggregate query with accumulators using mongodb driver in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm quite new in MongoDB and its interaction with java.
I'm using this driver

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and I want to perform this aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION').aggregate(
[
  {"$match":{"val.elem.0001":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{"FIELD_PATH":"$val.elem.0001"}},
  {$group:{_id:{"FIELD":{"$literal":"0001"}},
  "PATH":{"$addToSet":"$FIELD_PATH"}}}
]                                          
);
```

The java code I've written is the following (however I'm not sure if I use correctly the addToSet method):

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
new Document("$match", new Document("val.elem.0001",new Document("$exists",true))),
new Document("$project", new Document("FIELD_PATH","$val.elem.0001")),
new Document("$group", new Document("_id",new Document("FIELD", new Document("$literal", "0001"))
    .append("PATH",  Accumulators.addToSet("$PATH", "$FIELD_PATH"))))));
```

It is correct? Because I can't print the result on screen if I add the "append" part. The error that returns is 
*Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.BsonField*

So, to resume and make more readable and comprehensive what I've asked:

- Is the java representation of the query correct?
- If so, why I'm not able to print or access the result of the query?

Thanks in advance, if you need more informations, I'm ready to provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yous usage of api is incorrect.

Change your aggregation to below ( stick with `Document` for expressions)

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
       new Document("$match", new Document("val.elem.0001",new Document("$exists",true))),
       new Document("$project", new Document("FIELD_PATH","$val.elem.0001")),
       new Document("$group", new Document("_id",new Document("FIELD", new Document("$literal", "0001"))).append("PATH", new Document("$addToSet", "$FIELD_PATH")))));
```

`BsonField` is a helper class primarily built to provide data holder for `Accumulators` which return `key` and `Bson` value pair. So it is not meant to be used as value type. When use with helper methods, it is converted into `Document` and serialized using document codec.

You can rework your aggregation to use helper methods (`Filters`, `Projections` `Accumulators` & `Aggregates`)

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
       Aggregates.match(Filters.exists("val.elem.0001")),
       Aggregates.project(Projections.computed("FIELD_PATH","$val.elem.0001")),
       Aggregates.group( new Document("FIELD", new Document("$literal", "0001")), Accumulators.addToSet("PATH", "$FIELD_PATH"))));
```

You can further reduce the aggregation by using static imports.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.addToSet;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.group;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.project;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.computed;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;

AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(asList(
       match(Filters.exists("val.elem.0001")),
       project(computed("FIELD_PATH","$val.elem.0001")),
       group( new Document("FIELD", new Document("$literal", "0001")), addToSet("PATH", "$FIELD_PATH"))));
```

For more information

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/

Comment: The first aggregation you've written does not work, beacause fails in the interpretation of $addToSet. However the others are perfect, so thanks a lot for helping me! I will use this approach when using aggregators.